# Issue matching with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to match the following rules:

1. a word is consisted only of letters, digits, apostrophes, hyphens and underscores
2. start with a letter or apostrophe followed by letter
3. do not contain sequence of 2 or more apostrophes, underscores or hyphens
4. end with a letter, digit or apostrophe preceded by the letter s or apostrophe followed by s

So far I have a few regexes built:

For rule 2 I have built

```
^[']?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

For rule 3 I have built

```
(?!.*[-_'][-_'])(?=[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

but for a test string `abc def''ghi` it matches `ghi` not `abc`

For rule 4 I have built

`.*[a-zA-Z0-9](?:'s)?(?:s')?$`

but for a test string `test's abc'` it does not match anything but it should match `test's`

I am looking for some advice for rule 3 and 4 on how to improve my regex so they work

Comment: @trincot mistake when writing down the rules. Have updated them now.

Comment: rule 3 should mention the underscore?

Comment: Would [`^(?!.*[-'_]{2})'?[a-z][\w'-]*([a-z]|s')$`](https://regex101.com/r/ob2BLl/20) meet your requirements (ignoring case)?

Comment: Are you trying to write one single regex that matches each rule, or a different regex per rule?

Comment: @KhauriMcClain I am trying to do it regex per rule but I don't mind splitting them up if it can help

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/4AXS5P/1) working for you?

Comment: @Toto it works perfectly if words are separated by a new line. However my string I am matching against the regex will have several words on the same line separated by a space

Comment: [updated](https://regex101.com/r/4AXS5P/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:^|\s)\K(?!'')['a-z](?:['_-]?[a-z0-9])+['_-]?(?:(?<!')'s|s'|[a-z])(?=\s|$)
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\s)            # non capture group, beginning of line OR space
\K                  # forget all we've seen until this position
(?!'')              # negative lookahead, not two apos.
['a-z]              # apos. or letter
(?:                 # start non capture group
    ['_-]?          # apos, dash or underscore, optional
    [a-z0-9]        # a letter or digit
)+                  # group may appear 1 or more times
['_-]?              # apos, dash or underscore, optional
(?:                 # start non capture group
    (?<!')          # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't apos before
    's              # apos and s
  |                 # OR
    s'              # s and apos
  |                 # OR
    [a-z]           # a letter
)                   # end group
(?=\s|$)            # lookahead, make sure we have a space or end of line after
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4AXS5P/7)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Thank you

Comment: This regex fails for `a123's'd` which according to the rules should match.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi: Good catch, fixed.

Comment: @Toto I have one question. Is it possible to make it work without variable length lookbehind (?<=^|\s) as perl's regex does not support it ?

Comment: @J.Doolie: You can use a non capture group `(?:^|\s)` and, better, followed by `\K` that means, forget all that exists until this position, `(?:^|\s)\K['a-z](?:[a-z0-9]['_-]?)+(?:(?<!')'s|s'|[a-z])(?=\s|$)`

Comment: @Toto Thanks a lot that made it work. One more issue. The regex is not matching words like `o'clock` which is a valid word based on the rules

Comment: @J.Doolie: Is [this updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/4AXS5P/7) working?

Comment: @Toto Yes, perfect. Thanks a lot!